# jquery slider not setting value up to 2 decimals

Tags: jquery, sliders

1-
the value on slider is showing $10 and not whowing 10.00 ,
 and more ! 
2
and how we set the slider like this is 
http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/demo.html 
Predefined List, Equal Steps & Snap

Comment: are you using the same slider which is mentioned in the link?

Comment: not same ,,,, have modified form it

Comment: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?0qRLJKK8 ............ user like this but the value is shown on the pointer,,

Comment: as in the above link this is take the step of 10 and not take the step of 5 , but have the variable step that is different in different cases ..... and showing value in round .... but i need 10.00 like this

Answer (score 0):

Use `toFixed()`:

```
var x = 10;
x.toFixed(2); // outputs 10.00
```

Comment: var ids_value = round(jQuery("#minimum_monthly_payment_value").val(),0).toFixed(2);
 jQuery("#MonthlypaymentSlider").slider('value',ids_value);

Comment: use this but it is showing in console but not setting on sliders

Comment: jQuery("#MonthlypaymentSlider").slider({ 
                                    step:1,
                                    //round: 1, 
                                    format: { format: "#,##0.##" },           
                                    dimension: '$',
                                    planclass:'', 
                                    planvalue:'',
                                    skin: "round",
                                    sliderid:1,
                                    v_value:24,

Comment: onstatechange: function( value ){
                                    var current_step = jQuery('#cal_no_of_month').val();
                                    
                                    calculatePaymentbyMonth(value);
                                    } 

});